# json column formatting - change txtcontent onhover or active css link?

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, json, formatting

I have a button for a flow that users can click in a SharePoint library [modern experience].  I'm wondering if it's possible to change the txtcontent of the button after the button is active?   Just want to have something that alerts the end user they were successful in initiating the flow?

Comment: There is no event that you can capture and update the txtContent of the button after it's have been already clicked. However, you can have another field/column like a status column which the flow can update, and in JSON formatting button can be hid or label can be changed based on that field's value. See [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289843/power-automate-run-single-workflow-on-same-item-at-any-one-time)

Answer (score 0):

The txtcontent is "static" and we cannot change the value in txtcontent afte button is cliciking.   That is beyond the scope of JSON formatting.

As a workaround, you could update some column value in the flow. And the txtcontent refers to this column. So after clicking the button> trigger the flow > update the column value > the txtcontent would be changed